# How to use headerView completion block using SDWebImage in Swift 4.2?

Tags: swift4.2

I'm trying to figure out a way to push images that are loaded via SDWebImage on the headerView, to a view where the image can be viewed in headerView.

I tried this closure method 
sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString), completed: {
                (image, error, cacheType, url) in

but i am getting this error //Value of type 'UIView?' has no member 'sd_setImage'

//code line where the error happen

**self.headerView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: flowerImageURL), completed: { (image, error,  cache, url) in**

Answer (score 1):

SDWebImage used to display the image in UIImageView, UIButton, MKAnnotationView and not for UIView. It clearly describe in README.md

https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage

> This library provides an async image downloader with cache support. For convenience, we added categories for UI elements like UIImageView, UIButton, MKAnnotationView.
>    Categories for UIImageView, UIButton, MKAnnotationView adding web image and cache management

So, you can create imageView inside the headerView and use the "sd_setImage" from that imageview

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: urlString), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Link to: [HowToUse](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/blob/master/Docs/HowToUse.md)